# Bug in Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 4

Tags: entity-framework, ef-power-tools

Please let me know if this is not the correct place to submit a bug report for the EF Power Tools.

I assume the version marked BETA is still the latest and greatest version to use. I'm using it with EF 6.1.1

There is a bug in reverse engineering tables with composite primary keys.
My database has a table with it's PK defined as:

(
    [TableId] ASC,
    [AppDefID] ASC
)

note that TableId is the first column, and AppDefId the second.

but the generated code defined the PK as:

this.HasKey(t => new { t.AppDefID, t.TableId  });

Note the order of the columns in the PK definition don't match that in the database.  When the types of the columns is different, and another entity attempts to set a relationship to this entity, it will generate a model validation exception:

DataElementRule_RuleAppEntity_Target_DataElementRule_RuleAppEntity_Source: : The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role. 
The type of property 'TableId' on entity 'DataElementRule' does not match the type of property 'AppDefID' on entity 'RuleAppEntity' in the referential constraint 'DataElementRule_RuleAppEntity'.

The work around is to manually correct the order of the HasKey() parameters to match that of the database.

Comment: 1. Bugs should be logged to the [Entity Framework Project](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/).  2. Model generation is now part of the ADO.NET wizard after installing the latest Entity Framework Tools.  [Download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762) [Walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620)  3. It looks this is a known bug ([WI#868](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/868)) and has been fixed.  Warning: The models that are generated now are built differently than in the old EF Power Tools Addon.

Comment: That's a lot of great information.  Thank you.  Do you know if its possible to generate separate mapping files rather than using data annotations when generating the POCO classes?

Comment: I don't think that's possible with the latest EF Tools, no.  If you really want separate mapping files, you have to stick with the old Power Tools (and tweak the models every time you regenerate) or use [Simon Hughes' Reverse POCO Generator](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838), or update and bugfix the old Power Tools yourself (I think the source is in CodePlex).